# Trying to connect to a device based wireless set up on a ship

Tags: wifi

I'm on a ship in the Canadian Arctic and trying to link up to a wireless network that has been set up on a Windows 7 laptop, this is connected to the satellite system.  My MacBook Pro shows the signal under device when I click on the wireless symbol on the top right tool bar.  When I click on it and it connects with a check mark, all I get at the top is a greyed out computer network icon symbol.  What do I need to do under wireless network connections to make this work?
[image]
Here a couple of pics to show you what I am looking at.enter image description here

Thanks, Captain Marc

Comment: I think you should try connecting from the "network" preferences panel in the system preferences. It will show you more than the pull down menu. Then make sure your security protocols match. WPA, WPA2 etc.

Comment: I've tried all suggestions, everything has been done as suggested, but still no joy.  I can temporarily plug into the satellite connection for conductivity.  However having wireless access would make my work much easier here on  this ship.  Note latest screen capture of network status indicated that I am connected, however it still shows up as a greyed out device icon in the top status bar, where there should be a wireless signal strength icon...?  Any other suggestions.  Thanks Captain Marc   Screen Shot 2017-10-16 at 10.13.58.png

Comment: Unable to paste the screen capture.  Comments should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I would presume from what we are seeing in the WiFi menu that the Mac is connecting but not being given an IP address by the Windows 7 laptop. It's hard to know exactly without also seeing the "Network" preference pane with WiFi selected.

Check [this article](http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-7/how-to-share-an-internet-connection-in-windows-7/) on sharing an internet connection on Windows.

You might also check that the WiFi on your Mac is set to use DHCP to get an IP adddress. In "Network" preferences click on the WiFi network then click the "Advanced" button and in Advanced click on "TCP/IP".

[image]

Make sure "Using DHCP" is selected.

Comment: That's a Windows ad-hoc network he's connected to meaning it's "device to device".  The Windows setup is incorrect.

Comment: I assumed that but not knowing enough about Windows I left that bit up to the article in the link. :)